# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string error in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out this error in PHP:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

The line I have the error is this one:

`$et_theme_options[$option_name] = $new_value;`

I appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Done any debugging? If this line throws the error then presumably $et_theme_options must be a string rather than an array (as the code seems to assume it will be). If you didn't expect that, then debug further back to discover how it got like that